# How to extract a number from a string using wildcard characters in xslt?

Tags: xslt, wildcard

I have a selection of names, starting with numbers from 1 to 13:

```
<description>
</description>
<short>1EN-1</short>
</description>
<description>
<short>2EN-1</short>
</description>
```

and so on till

```
<description>
<short>13EN-1</short>
</description>
```

I need to be able to extract the first number.

I have used the following code:

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with(description/short, '1')">1</xsl:when>
```

Unfortunately, this string returns 1 for both the description/short beginning with 1 and the ones beginning with 11, 12 and 13. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the string following the leading number ("EN" in your example) known in advance? If yes, you can simply use the `substring-before()` function to extract the number. If not, what **is** known about the next character/s? Or about the maximum size the number can be?

Comment: get the substring before '-' and use double translate to filter the numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

In an `xsl:choose` the *first* `when` test that matches will be the one used, so put the longer prefix tests before the shorter ones:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="starts-with(description/short, '13')">...</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="starts-with(description/short, '12')">...</xsl:when>
  <!-- ... -->
  <xsl:when test="starts-with(description/short, '2')">...</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="starts-with(description/short, '1')">...</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```